# Bootstrap side by side form elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to match a similar layout to this picture using bootstrap 3+. [image]

I have all of it working except for the Ends section where there are text boxes next to the radio buttons. Could someone help me with the syntax.

I created a jsFiddle where I am at. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pricejt/9xd78va5/1/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ends:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="ends" id="endsAfter" value="EndsAfter"> After                     </label>
 <label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="afterOccur" id="afterOccur" disabled> occurrences </label>
 </div>
</div>
<div cass="input-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="ends" id="endsOn" value="EndsOn">On</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-4" name="onDate" id="onDate" disabled />
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that may give you something to work with at the very least. There's nothing special about it, the only addition is some CSS to keep the **Summary** label consistent with the rest of the form. It just uses offsets to keep everything lined up correctly and groups controls that need to stay together. You can change the column values to whatever you actually need them to be, just remember to keep them consistent across the form. See [Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

See working Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#RepeatByBlock {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  label.summary {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Repeats">Repeats:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <Select name="Repeats" id="Repeats" class="form-control">
          <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
          <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
        </Select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="RepeatEvery">Repeats Every:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="RepeatEvery" id="RepeatEvery" class="form-control">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Weeks</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Repeat On:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="sunday" id="sunday" title="Sunday" /> S
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="monday" id="monday" title="Monday" /> M
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="tuesday" id="tuesday" title="Tuesday" /> T
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="wednesday" id="wednesday" title="Wednesday" /> W
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="thursday" id="thursday" title="Thursday" /> T
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="friday" id="friday" title="Friday" /> F
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="saturday" id="saturday" title="Saturday" /> S
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="RepeatByBlock" name="RepeatByBlock">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Multiple Time</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="RepeatBy" id="RepeatByMonth" value="month" checked>Day of the Month</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="startsOn">Starts On:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startsOn" id="startsOn" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Ends:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">Never
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">After
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="afterOccur" id="afterOccur" disabled>
      </div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="afterOccur">Occurrences</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">On
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="onOccur" id="onOccur" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="summary">Summary:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        Weekly on Monday, until Jan 19, 2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Done</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This code actually matches the example that I was trying to create. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about you try building forms on bootstrap by dragging and dropping form elements from here http://bootsnipp.com/forms , i guess that would exactly build what you have asked for.

**Edit:**

Drag from elements from left to right and view HTML. Try building here http://bootsnipp.com/j87klPolka/formbuilder3.html It's more clear

Comment: Awesome @K.C. ! I didn't know bootsnipp! I'm gonna keep it in mind for my next form!

Comment: @VirtuaCreative I'm glad you found it useful. Bootsnipp is rich resource for bootstrap components. Also you can accept the answer if it solves you problem.

Comment: Sorry @K.C.,  I was just giving a look at this question and saw your comment. I'm not the one who asked..  :)

Comment: Ooops, not your comment, your answer! Very useful yes! ;)

Comment: @VirtuaCreative Lol yeah, Sorry it's fine.

Comment: @K.C. i didn't know about this either. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @K.C it appears you can't put radio buttons and text box side by side within that bootsnipp tool or i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @pricejt do you mean `label` ?, click on the form element after you drag-drop, then you can change label, value..